# Automatic Ajax request to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, geolocation

How can I send some data via ajax to controller without click event. I mean when user lands on HOME page, i want to obtain his current latitude and longitude and I was able to get his/her current coordinates.But my problem is that I am unable to send this latitude and longitude to particular route,so that i can search nearest hotels based on his current coordinates.

my code:

```
<script>
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        console.log(position);
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;//this gives latitude
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;//this gives longitude

        $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost:8000/coordinates',
            type:'get',
            data:{latitude:lat,longitude:lng},


            success:function(data)
            {
               alert('success');
            }

        });
    });
}

</script>
```

My route

```
Route::get('/coordinates', 'SearchController@getCoordinate');
```

Controller:

```
public function getCoordinate(Request $request){
    return $request->latitude;// i am getting nothing here. i expect to get 
   latitude of user
}
```

How can i obtain this coordinates in `getCoordinate` function of my controller when user visit the website.

Comment: Do `dd($request->all())` to check if you have any data in the first place.

Comment: done but  got null array []

Comment: Why not change your ajax call and pass the parameters as query string instead? `'http://localhost:8000/coordinates?latitude='+lat+'&longitude='+lng` then in your controller, attempt to check it with `request()->all()` (this is a function not the $request variable)? I suspect you may be using the wrong Request class though.

Comment: Thanks i will try it

Answer (score 0):

"without click event"

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //paste your script here
})
```

it mean the javascript would run your code when the document is ready

Answer (score -1):

Change your  route to 
Route::get('/coordinates', ['uses'=>'SearchController@getCoordinate']);